# issue finding why these loops are flagged as "a statement with no effect" (warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value])

Tags: c, multithreading

I am unsure how to clear these warnings because the 'for' and 'while' loops they flag are productive in my program..

(" warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]" and i  ran -Wall at compile time)

```
/* Creation of specified # of threads */
pthread_t thread_array[thread_num]; // initialize space
int i = 0, rc;
for(i; i< thread_num; i++) 
{
    rc = pthread_create(&thread_array[i], NULL, summation, (void*)NULL); // create new thread
                                                                        // that starts at "summation"       
    if(rc != 0) // check if thread was created successfully
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nCouldn't create thread\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (i;` is the problem. The statement `i` has no effect. If you don't need `i` after the loop, then `i` should be declared in the `for` statement itself: `for (int i=0; i<thread_num; i++)` Your other option is simply to leave the first statement empty: `for(; i<thread_num; i++)`

Comment: Also, if this is your actual code then `else { // do nothing }` is useless and can be removed.

Comment: @user3386109: … and the other, other option is to write `for (i = 0; i < thread_num; i++)` (and there's then no need to initialize `i` in its definition).